# CakePHP4 - How to create multiple user login with the Authentication plugin?

Tags: authentication, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

There are two types of users in the application I am developing. `Users` (table `users.sql`) for frontend users and `AdminUsers` (table `admin_users.sql`) for administration.

In CakePHP3, I solved this problem as follows with `AuthComponent` in `AppController`:

```php
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();

    // ...

    //user login
    if (!empty($this->request->params['prefix']) AND
        $this->request->params['prefix'] == 'admin'
    ) {
        $this->setAdminLogin();
    }else{
        $this->setUserLogin();
        $this->Auth->allow();
    }

    // ...
}
```

```php
//frontend users
public function setUserLogin()
{
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'authorize' => ['Controller'],
        'loginAction' => [
            'controller' => 'Users',
            'action' => 'login'
        ],
        'loginRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Users',
            'action' => 'edit'
        ],
        'logoutRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Users',
            'action' => 'login'
        ],
        'authError' => false,
        'authenticate' => [
            'Xety/Cake3CookieAuth.Cookie' => [
                'userModel' => 'Users',
                'scope' => ['Users.active' => 1],
                'fields' => ['username' => 'email','password' => 'password'],
            ],
            'Form' => [
                'userModel' => 'Users',
                'scope' => ['Users.active' => 1],
                'fields' => ['username' => 'email','password' => 'password'],
                'passwordHasher' => [
                    'className' => 'Fallback',
                    'hashers' => ['Default']
                ]
            ],
        ],
        'storage' =>  ['className' => 'Session', 'key' => 'Auth.User']
    ]);
}
```

```php
//admin users
public function setAdminLogin()
{
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'authorize' => ['Controller'],
        'loginAction' => [
            'controller' => 'AdminUsers',
            'action' => 'login',
        ],
        'loginRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'AdminHelps',
            'action' => 'index'
        ],
        'logoutRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'AdminUsers',
            'action' => 'login'
        ],
        'authError' => false,
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'userModel' => 'AdminUsers',
                'scope' => ['AdminUsers.active' => 1],
                'fields' => ['username' => 'email','password' => 'password'],
                'passwordHasher' => [
                    'className' => 'Fallback',
                    'hashers' => ['Default']
                ]
            ],
        ],
        'storage' =>  ['className' => 'Session', 'key' => 'Auth.AdminUser']
    ]);
}
```

How can I do the same thing in CakePHP4 version with Authentication plugin? How can I create multiple user login?

Comment: Did you read through cakephp 4 tutorial on authorization plugin? This allows you to set authorization on specific controllers so if your users have "roles" (i.e. admin) you can perform a check  if ($user-role == admin) {
/*allow access */
        $this->Authentication->skipAuthorization();
    }

Recommend going through tutorial for basics https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/tutorials-and-examples/cms/authorization.html, there's also this post which gives additional details. https://www.cakedc.com/jorge_gonzalez/2020/05/19/working-with-cakephp-authorization

Comment: I read the documentation. Unfortunately, I did not find the ability to create a model different than the 'Users' model for authentication. I need TWO different models 'Users' and 'AdminUsers'. In CakePHP3 version this problem is solved this way: https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers

Comment: If you're setup is flexible my opinion is that it would be easier to have a single user model/table. Add a "role" column that tells you if the user is an admin, member, user, etc... That way you can set the authorization of any controller action based on their role. The Auth component setup examples show "admin" users being routed to controller actions with the "admin" prefix but that's still in one model. If you're setup is not flexible you should still be able to do something similar with Autorization... setting admin users authorized for specific actions vs non-admin users.

Comment: @user3661042 How did you manage to solve this? I'm also in the same situation. I have implemented users login based on multiple tables in CakePHP 3.x. Would you mind sharing how to implement this in 4.x when using Authentication plugin. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to solve the problem I still use 'AuthComponent'. If you use the 'Authentication plugin' the table is always just one 'users.sql' in which you define different roles.

Comment: Did you try writing your own resolver? So you are able to build logic which decides which table to use:
https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/2/en/identifiers.html#writing-your-own-resolver